# A column named [column name] already belongs to this DataTable when form is reloaded

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a data grid view (designed for user input which is then made into a data table in the database). When I load the form, everything loads as I want it to. However, if I exit the form, and reload it I get the following error message:

```
A column named 'line' already belongs to this DataTable
```

'Line' being the first column name I have declared;

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
#region loadtable
public void newquoteForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getCompanyInfo();
    loadTable();
}
private void loadTable()
{
    dt.Clear();
    DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add("Line");
    dt.Columns.Add("Item Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Item Description");
    dt.Columns.Add("Retail Price");
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier Number");
    dt.Columns.Add("Quantity Required");
    dt.Columns.Add("In Stock");
    dt.Columns.Add("Cost Price");
    dt.Columns.Add("Total Cost");
    dt.Columns.Add("Total Retail");
    dt.Columns["Line"].AutoIncrement = true;
    dt.Columns["Line"].AutoIncrementSeed = -1;
    dt.Columns["Line"].AutoIncrementStep = 1;
    dt.Columns["Line"].ReadOnly = true;
    dt.Columns["Item Name"].ReadOnly = true;
    dt.Columns["Item Description"].ReadOnly = true;
    dt.Columns["Cost Price"].ReadOnly = true;
    dt.Columns["In Stock"].ReadOnly = true;
    dt.Columns["Retail Price"].ReadOnly = true;
    dt.Columns["Supplier Number"].ReadOnly = true;

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can move your `loadTable` method call to the form ctor.

Comment: When form reloads, nobody creates it again. So, your `dt` already has columns. I suggest to remove `loadTable` call from `Form.Load` handler and add it to the form constructor, which called ones.

Comment: Of course, if you want to clear a table, you will still have to do this in the `Load` handler

Comment: And it was something that simple, could you post it as an answer so I can complete the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smth like this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

public newquoteForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    loadTable();
}

public void newquoteForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getCompanyInfo();
    clearTable();
}

private void clearTable()
{
   DataRow dr;
   dt.Clear();
   dr = dt.NewRow();
   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void loadTable()
{
   dt.Columns.Add("Line");
   dt.Columns.Add("Item Name");
   dt.Columns.Add("Item Description");
   dt.Columns.Add("Retail Price");
   dt.Columns.Add("Supplier Number");
   dt.Columns.Add("Quantity Required");
   dt.Columns.Add("In Stock");
   dt.Columns.Add("Cost Price");
   dt.Columns.Add("Total Cost");
   dt.Columns.Add("Total Retail");
   dt.Columns["Line"].AutoIncrement = true;
   dt.Columns["Line"].AutoIncrementSeed = -1;
   dt.Columns["Line"].AutoIncrementStep = 1;
   dt.Columns["Line"].ReadOnly = true;
   dt.Columns["Item Name"].ReadOnly = true;
   dt.Columns["Item Description"].ReadOnly = true;
   dt.Columns["Cost Price"].ReadOnly = true;
   dt.Columns["In Stock"].ReadOnly = true;
   dt.Columns["Retail Price"].ReadOnly = true;
   dt.Columns["Supplier Number"].ReadOnly = true;
}
```